# String split based on repetitions

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string value (`"11112233"`). I want to split this string and separate it to 3 different value.

```
Val 1 = 1111
val 2 = 22    
val 3 = 33
```

I searched a lot, its possible with characters like (`/`) or other symbols.
Something else, My number is always different, so i cant split it by enter the exact string.
I want to do something like this:

```
var myVal = "11112233";
var lastVal = myVal.split(0 , 3); // split from index 0 till index 3
```

How i can do it?
Thanks

Comment: simply you can do like this '11112233'.split(/(1+|2+|3+)/). but need regex improvements

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
'121112233'.match(/(\d)\1*/g) // ["1", "2", "111", "22", "33"]
```

`\1*` means "same as previous match, zero or more times".

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
myVal='11112233'
myVal.match(/(\d)\1+/g); //["1111", "22", "33"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use object to solve this.

```
var str = '11112233';

var strObj = {};

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
     if(strObj[str[i]]) {
         strObj[str[i]]+=str[i];
     } else {
        strObj[str[i]] = str[i];
     }
}

for (var key in strObj) {
  if (strObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key + " -> " + strObj[key]);
  }
}
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/7qj3szo2/

Comment: it should be more efficient in terms of time and space complexity.

Comment: Not sure: http://jsperf.com/regexp-vs-hardcoded, as far as jsperf is reliable :-D

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) function.

You can use it like you've written in your question:

```
var myVal = "11112233";
var lastVal = myVal.substr(0, 3); // "1111"
```

Comment: Actually, the question is pretty unclear saying "some thing like this". It's still a valid answer imho.

Answer (score 2):

To complement above answers, here's solution not using regex.

```
function partition(acc, value){

  var last = acc[acc.length-1];
  if(last && last[0] == value) acc[acc.length-1] += value;
  else acc = acc.concat(value);

  return acc;
}

var toInt = parseInt.bind(null, 10)

var x = ([[]]).concat("112233".split(''))
              .reduce(partition).map(toInt);

// [11, 22, 33]
```